# Google Sheets Query to SELECT * WHERE COLUMN CONTAINS certain content within a string (partial match)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to adapt a query that brings back rows from multiple google spreadsheets.
The query brings back rows when a column meets certain criteria specified in four cells (B1, B2, B3 or B4).  Specifically customer exact names.

I am trying to adapt the query to be able to bring back rows of information whenever another column contains certain criteria (partial match).  Specifically, if certain column contain specific email addresses within other information that the cell keeps. Sometimes not only the email address is stored, but the name and email address, for example:  Peter Piper peter@piper.com.  I would  like the query to bring back the row if certain column "contains" the email address, within a string.

Thanks in advance!

**ORIGINAL FORMULA**
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!B2,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B3,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B4,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B9,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B10,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B11,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B12,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B13,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B14,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B15,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B16,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B20,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B21,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B23,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B24,"Operaciones!A3:AZ");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B25,"Operaciones!A3:AZ")},CONCATENAR(*"SELECT * WHERE Col4='",B1,"' OR Col4='",B2,"' OR Col4='",B3,"' OR Col4='",B4,"'"*),1)

I have tried changing commas for % and & in:

Col4='",B1,"

Answer (score 0):

Change the equals to LIKE and then add the % to both sides before the cell reference

```
"...WHERE Col4 LIKE'%",B1,"%' OR Col4 LIKE '%",B2,"%' OR Col4 LIKE '%",B3,"%' OR Col4 LIKE'%",B4,"%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
"...WHERE Col4 MATCHES '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B1:B4)&"'", 1)
```

If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet. That will make it a lot easier to help you out.